# Sub select in bigquery with case statement

Tags: google-bigquery

Below Query when I execute gives me a result as below
(SELECT 
 
CASE 
           WHEN prodName CONTAINS('AAA') THEN 'AAA' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('BBB') THEN 'BBB' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('CCC') THEN 'CCC' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('DDD') THEN 'DDD' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('EEE') THEN 'EEE' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('FFF') THEN 'FFF' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('GGG') THEN 'GGG' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('HHH') THEN 'HHH' 
           ELSE 'Others' 
       END AS 
PROD_NAME, 
 EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user) AS Distinct_users 
FROM [mytable] 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
IGNORE CASE)

[image]



Below query which is same as above but I have given a subselect in order to omit records if PROD_NAME = aaa returns a different result where it aggregates distinct users having value 1 to others and shows diff result. 

SELECT PROD_NAME, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(users) AS Distinct_users 
FROM 
(SELECT 
 
CASE 
           WHEN prodName CONTAINS('AAA') THEN 'AAA' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('BBB') THEN 'BBB' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('CCC') THEN 'CCC' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('DDD') THEN 'DDD' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('EEE') THEN 'EEE' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('FFF') THEN 'FFF' 
  WHEN prodName CONTAINS('GGG') THEN 'GGG' 
          WHEN prodName CONTAINS('HHH') THEN 'HHH' 
           ELSE 'Others' 
       END AS 
PROD_NAME, 
 EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user) AS Distinct_users 
FROM [mytable] 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
IGNORE CASE)

[image]

Please let me know how to resolve the issue. I need the second query to provide same output as first but I do not need PROD_NAME = 'AAA'. I have included as case statement because my table contains several data such as 'aaa','AAA', 'aaa-in', 'Aaa' etc and I am grouping everything together to show the aggregate value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the second query to provide same output as first but I do not need PROD_NAME = 'AAA'

how about just simply adding HAVING clause as below

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('AAA') THEN 'AAA' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('BBB') THEN 'BBB' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('CCC') THEN 'CCC' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('DDD') THEN 'DDD' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('EEE') THEN 'EEE' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('FFF') THEN 'FFF' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('GGG') THEN 'GGG' 
    WHEN prodName CONTAINS('HHH') THEN 'HHH' 
    ELSE 'Others' 
  END AS 
  PROD_NAME, 
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user) AS Distinct_users 
FROM [mytable] 
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING PROD_NAME <> 'AAA'
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
IGNORE CASE
```